# mvc3 multiline text in a cell

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have text with "\n" in my database. How can i display the linebreaks in the index view (`<br />`)

Simple "replace" is not working, it gets encoded:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.name, "Details", new { id = item.personId })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.adresse.Replace("\n", "<br />")
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.tel1
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.infos
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing somehting like this, it is very important to encode the text, that is going to be shown, in order to avoid harmful javascript code

```
 @MvcHtmlString.Create(
          Html.Encode(item.adresse).Replace(Enviornment.NewLine, "<br />")
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is originally not entered by a user, or you have already sanitized it

```
@Html.Raw(item.adresse.Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Otherwise Cshift3iLike's answer is good for unsanitized input.